# How do I use a temp table across multiple c# calls

Tags: c#, sql, temp-tables

I have a C# application, using ADO.Net to connect to MSSQL

I need to create the table (with a dynamic number of columns), then insert many records, then do a select back out of the table.

Each step must be a separate C# call, although I can keep a connection/transaction open for the duration.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? If you drop all this data in temp tables to do so some searching on it, you'd be far better off just searching over the data using linq inside your application.

Comment: The issue is memory.  I'm getting a large amount of unsorted data streamed to me from a source. I need to wait until the full stream is done, and then sort it, and then process it. However, its up to a gigabyte or more worth of data. So I am inserting it into the database, sorting it in the database, and then streaming it back down in the resulting query, so that I never have to have the full dataset in RAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of temp tables in SQL Server, local temp tables and global temp tables. From the BOL:

> Prefix local temporary table names with single number sign (#tablename), and prefix global temporary table names with a double number sign (##tablename).

Local temp tables will live for *just* your current connection. Globals will be available for all connections. Thus, if you re-use (and you did say you could) the same connection across your related calls, you can just use a local temp table without worries of simultaneous processes interfering with each others' temp tables.

You can get more info on this from the **[BOL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx)**, specifically under the "Temporary Tables" section about halfway down.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that #Temp tables exist only within the Connection AND the Scope of the execution.
When the first call from C# to SQL completes, control passes up to a higher level of scope.

This is just as if you had a T-SQL script that called two stored procedures.  Each SP created a table named #MyTable.  The second SP is referencing a completly different table than the first SP.
However, if the parent T-SQL code created the table, both SP's could see it, but they can't see each others.

The solution here is to use ##Temp tables.  They cross scope and connections.
The danger though is that if you use a hard coded name, then two instances of your program running at the same time could see the same table.  So dynamically set the table name to something that will be always be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the repository pattern as far as dealing with this concept in C#.  This allows you to have a low level repository layer for data access where each method performs a task.  But the connection is passed in to the method and actual actions are performed with in a transaction scope.  This means you can theoretically call many different methods in your data access layer (implemented as repository) and if any of them fail you can roll back the whole operation.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

The other aspects of your question would be handled by standard sql where you can dynamically create a table, insert into it, delete from it, etc.  The tricky part here is keeping one transaction away from another transaction.  You might look to using temp tables...or you might simply have a 2nd database specifically for performing this dynamic table concept.

Comment: The c# part is not an issue, its just how to keep the table alive across multiple c# round trips.

Comment: This is the reason I don't suggest using a real temp table.  I would start your process by creating a table with a specific name for that particular process...then work off of that table...then kill it at the end of the transaction...or when the transaction fails.  Do this in a separate DB for performance and disk maintanence reasons.

Answer (score 1):

One way to extend the scope/lifetime of your single pound sign #Temp is to use a transaction.  For as long as the transaction lives, the #temp table continues to exist. You can also use  TransactionScope to give you the same effect, because TransactionScope creates an ambient transaction in the background.

The below test methods pass, proving that the #temp table contents survive between executions.

This may be preferable to using double-pound temp tables, because ##temp tables are global objects.  If you have more than one client that happens to use the same ##temp table name, then they could step on each other.  Also, ##temp tables do not survive a server restart, so their lifespan is technically not forever. IMHO it's best to control the scope of #temp tables because they're meant to be limited.

```
using System.Transactions;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using IsolationLevel = System.Data.IsolationLevel;

namespace TestTempAcrossConnection
{
   [TestClass]
   public class UnitTest1
   {
       private string _testDbConnectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=master;trusted_connection=true";
       class TestTable1
       {
           public int Col1 { get; set; }
           public string Col2 { get; set; }
       }
       [TestMethod]
       public void TempTableBetweenExecutionsTest()
       {
           using var conn = new SqlConnection(_testDbConnectionString);
           conn.Open();
           var tran = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
           conn.Execute("create table #test1(col1 int, col2 varchar(20))", transaction: tran);
           conn.Execute("insert into #test1(col1,col2) values (1, 'one'),(2,'two')", transaction: tran);
           var tableResult = conn.Query<TestTable1>("select col1, col2 from #test1", transaction: tran).ToList();
           Assert.AreEqual(1, tableResult[0].Col1);
           Assert.AreEqual("one", tableResult[0].Col2);
           tran.Commit();
       }

       [TestMethod] public void TempTableBetweenExecutionsScopeTest()
       {
           using var scope = new TransactionScope();
           using var conn = new SqlConnection(_testDbConnectionString);
           conn.Open();

           conn.Execute("create table #test1(col1 int, col2 varchar(20))");
           conn.Execute("insert into #test1(col1,col2) values (1, 'one'),(2,'two')");
           var tableResult = conn.Query<TestTable1>("select col1, col2 from #test1").ToList();
           Assert.AreEqual(2, tableResult[1].Col1);
           Assert.AreEqual("two", tableResult[1].Col2);
           scope.Complete();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you test that works?, I don't see it works that way

Comment: @cuongle I sure did.  It is in a test method after all.  When I ran it, I could see the rows returned that I'd just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I think you are doing this the hard way. Do all the steps in one stored proc.

Comment: I cannot do the steps in one stored proc, as the data to insert into the tables is not available yet.